# Создать дополнение к браузеру Chrome Android

Tags: javascript, java, android, android-sdk, google-chrome

Можно ли только для себя создать дополнение к браузеру Chrome Android?
Что для этого нужно?
Полностью декомпилировать приложение?
Читал статью, что Google заблокирует стороннее ПО, использующее инъекции кода в Chrome.
На Android такое возможно?

Answer (score 3):

В стабильной версии Chrome для Android отсутствует возможность использования дополнений. Дополнения в целом больше для десктопной версии. Изготавливая дополнение только для себя, вы потратите больше сил и времени, чем если обратитесь к более простым технологиям. Также не вполне ясно, зачем именно вам нужно такое дополнение. Можно сделать приложение на Android, которое будет содержать браузерное окно.

Comment: а браузерное окно будет открываться с помощью.chrome?

Comment: WebView - стандарнтый вариант в Android. Также есть вариант Chromeview, это opensource-разработка.